# Is there such a thing as a nightly build for Aptana Studio, and from where can we download it?

Tags: aptana

There's a bug for a feature I use in the recent update of Aptana Studio.  The bug tracker implies the issue is fixed, but implies that it will be included in an update in late May.  Does Aptana Studio have nightly builds that can be downloaded and if so from where?

I can't find anything in the forums or from google and the options on git hub look older and not official.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Go to http://preview.appcelerator.com where you can download nightly versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that shows how to get latest updates from Aptana Studio.

[What is the official release update URL for Aptana Studio 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812485/what-is-the-official-release-update-url-for-aptana-studio-3-0)

(Another answer here gave a link to Appcelerator.)

Here is how to get the beta version:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/beta/

Release Candidate:
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/rc/

This url can be used within Aptana to update to the nightly builds, but I have not tried it. It is for the plugin version of Aptana:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/nightly/site.xml