# What is the official release update URL for Aptana Studio 3.0?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I noticed today that there is a new version of Aptana Studio 3.2.1 out there.

Whenever I click on Help --> Check for Updates. It doesn't update it.

I am on 3.2.0 and according to the documentaion, I am not doing anything wrong:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Updating+the+Current+Version

A similar question seems to have been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182618/how-to-update-aptana-studio-to-the-latest) but the suggested update url "http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/" is refused.

Which is the official update link for releases?

**Update:**

Thanks to Eric's advice, I have updated it on my desktop to `Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.1.201207261642` this is the same version on my laptop, which has installed 3.2.1 directly.

The naming convention is still a bit confusing.  Usually RC (Release Candidate) is a bug-free Beta version that is as the name says just a candidate but not the actual release. It feels wrong updating the actual release through an preview.rc url.
My gut feeling tells me this rc url would contain very soon a new release candidate update that is not released on the actual website.

I leave that still open hoping for someone official from Aptana giving a statement. Thanks :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which type of install you are updating, as they have different URLs.

For updating a Eclipse plug-in version, the update URL is indeed:

http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/

However, for the standalone version, the URL is:

http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/

To confirm, the RC stream will have builds that are almost ready to release. They are undergoing final QA. They may have bugs, and there may be several RC releases before we get to a final release.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks Ingo, therefore if someone wanted to stick with proper Releases only, the only way would be to delete the Aptana directory and downloading the new released version, correct? That can't be done by updates. Btw I meant the Aptana Standalone version in my post.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*For the beta release,* I had to add the update site by hand, using the URL:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/beta/

Also, I had to be in Aptana as Administrator (Windows super-user).

Maybe that will help.

*Edit:* per comment, it looks like this would be the corresponding release candidate URL:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/rc/

I have not tried that however and would be interested in knowing if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But isn't that the latest beta releases update link?

Comment: Additionally: [Stable updates](http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/stable/), [Release Candidate updates](http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/rc/), as listed on [official channel](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/)